# Postgresql Execute function

Tags: postgresql, execute

I'm trying to create a function that searches for a string in one of the table fields and then returns a new table of users. Basically, inside one table I have

```
create table fooSearchTable (
    id          integer, -- PG: serial
    name        LongName unique not null,
    queryDef    LongString not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

where `queryDef` is a string that holds another query to execute. For example one row might be

```
1 | resultName | select * from users where users.id = '4'
```

I was given this function format to start off the function with

```
create or replace function searchUsers(_searchName text) returns table (userID integer) as $$
begin
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```

I need to run a SQL query to find the row the `_searchName` matches with that is

```
select queryDef from fooSearchTable f
where f.name = _searchName;
```

this would return the string, but I don't know how to execute this string in the function so i can get a table of userIDs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I gather you've read what the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) says about this topic?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev yup a little confused how to apply it from the one shown in the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
create or replace function searchUsers(_searchName text) 
   returns table (userID integer) 
as $$
  _query varchar;
begin
  select queryDef
     into _query 
  from fooSearchTable f
  where f.name = _searchName;

  return query execute _query;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

(Not tested, so it might contain syntax erros)

Note that `select ..  into` requires the statment to return exactly one row, otherwise you'll get an error at runtime. You either need to make sure the condition achieves this or apply a `limit` clause on the select statement.

This is explained here:
 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54092